# Vector Projection - Making sure my vehicle can only accelerate on the floor/surface

Tags: c++, vector, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I am facing a problem with my "hover" vehicle. I only want it to move when it is on the ground.

I have come across vector projection, projecting one vector on to another vector.

With this my vehicle will be able to go down ramps with acceleration, and up ramps, and alley oops, curved ramps ETC.

However, this is all theory to me.

Unreal Four Engine doesn't have a Vector on Vector static function in the API, or maybe I am wrong [FVector](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FVector/index.html)

For now, I have implemented this.

```
FVector test = FVector::VectorPlaneProject(StaticMeshComponent->GetForwardVector(), surfaceImpactNormal);
FVector surfaceForwardDirection = StaticMeshComponent->GetForwardVector() - test;
FVector force = (surfaceForwardDirection* m_forwardAcl) * AxisValue;
force = force * GetWorld()->DeltaTimeSeconds * StaticMeshComponent->GetMass();

StaticMeshComponent->AddForce(force);
```

My aim is to get something like in the picture:

[image: Example]

Is there anyway I can get my vehicle to accelerate back and fourth with out flying off into the sun set (if it's nose is pointing at that angle).

Comment: look for scalar / dot product

Comment: @tobi303 dot product returns a float though? What do I do with that float?

Comment: projection of u onto v is : `v.u * v/||v||`

Comment: Yeah, I know the formula off a video on YouTube, will I have to implement this, or is there no function in UE4?

Comment: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FVector/DotProduct/index.html

Comment: actually UE4 has exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: @tobi303 I should have paid attention in my GCSE classes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FVector` you are using has a method to project one vector onto another one: [FVector::ProjectOnTo](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FVector/ProjectOnTo/index.html)

In your case you would call it like this:

```
FVector UprojectedOnV = U.ProjectOnTo(V);
```

Comment: Yes, I have come across, but I am not sure how it would be used. 

FVector foo = FVector::ProjectOnTo(I can either pass in U or V here).

Comment: Excellent example! Clear and makes sense.